# Problem resizing Fedora partitions using GParted

Tags: fedora, partition, gparted

[image]

Hello everyone,

I wan to to resize the size of my current Linux partition. In the picture my fedora system is the sdb5 (it is on my SSD), the 105GB unallocated space was once the space of a windows partition I will no longer use, what I want to do is to expand the size of my Linux partition but the /boot/efi and /boot (sdb2 and sdb4 correspondingly) are in between my two partitions. What can I do? I feel not completely comfortable with terminal optiona so I prefer a GUI solution.

Comment: Previous paritions can not be expanded. You have to move data from sdb5 to unalloc. Then expand the ualloc. Or use unalloc. as `/home`.

Answer (score 2):

*I hope I'm not missing something obvious here.*  The point of LVM is that you can use multiple partitions as one single file system.  One of the useful points about this is that you can extend a file system onto any new partition (even spanning across disks).

So in your case you can just create a new partition in the allocated space, add this to your volume group and the extend your logical volume to use the extra space.

I'm afraid I don't have instructions on doing this with gparted but here's a relativly straight forward tutorial on how to expand an LVM by adding a partition.

https://www.systutorials.com/5621/extending-a-mounted-ext4-file-system-on-lvm-in-linux/

The simple version of the steps are:

1. Create a new (un-formatted) partition (use [`cfdisk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cfdisk.8.html) or `fdisk`)
2. Setup the partition as a an LVM physical volume [`pvcreate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvcreate.8.html)
3. Add the new physical volume to your volume group using [`vgextend`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgextend.8.html)
4. Extend the logical volume to use the extra space using [`lvextend`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvextend.8.html)
5. (If not done in step 4) resize the ext4 file system using [`resize2fs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvextend.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you move the /boot and /boot/efi partitions to the beginning of the disk, so that the unallocated space is adjacent to the partition you actually want to add it to. Once that is complete, then you can resize the LVM partition into the adjacent free space.

Since you can't move a mounted filesystem, you should first boot your system with the [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) image to ensure the file system you wish to move isn't mounted.